# ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_10' in the referenced table 'branch'

Tags: mysql

I try to create a table for the company database. 
As I tried to add some foreign keys in there, something goes wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  salary INT,
  super_id INT,
  branch_id INT unique
);

CREATE TABLE branch (
  branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_name VARCHAR(40),
  mgr_id INT,
  mgr_start_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)
REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(super_id)
REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

The "alter table employee" part to add foreign key (branch) failed with the following statement.

```
ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_10' in the referenced table 'branch'
```

Could this be some problem with my setting?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c9d0352678009510004479d568dcf7f6)

Comment: Unrelated: you probably don't want a `unique` constraint on column `employee(branch_id)` - unless you have only one employee per branch.