# ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constaint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hey so I'm on my first project with a complexe database :)

I have created all of my tables and I am now updating them to add the Foreign Keys (I had an issue so I decided to add Foreign Keys after creating all the tables).

Here the ERR Diagram that describe the project : [click to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxbMh.png)

The exact error i get : `ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_user_in_org__org_roles1' in the referenced table 'org_roles'`

---

I've searched my error but i didn't found a solution to my problem here some of the best I found :

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122148/er-fk-no-index-parent-failed-to-add-the-foreign-key-constraint-missing-index-f)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909178/er-fk-no-index-parent-failed-to-add-the-foreign-key-constraint-missing-index-f)

---

The tables concerned (simplified) and the update command :

```sql
------------------
-- Tables setup --
------------------

-- A role is unique for an org but differents orgs can have a role that have the same label
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students.org_roles (
  `org_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `label` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`org_id`, `label`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- The users are unique
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students.users (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (`id` ASC));

-- The orgs are unique 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students.organizations (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- The table that match a user in an org with a specified role (= label in the org_role table)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students.user_in_org (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `org_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `role` TEXT(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `org_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC));

------------------------
-- The update command --
------------------------

ALTER TABLE students.user_in_org ADD
  (CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__users1
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES students.users(`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__organizations1
    FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES students.organizations(`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__org_roles1
    FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES students.org_roles(`label`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)
And please forgive me if my english isn't that fluent :/

Answer (score 0):

For

```
CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__org_roles1
FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES students.org_roles(`label`)
```

You need a index on the table org_roles for the column label

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students.org_roles (
  `org_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `label` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  KEy (`label`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`org_id`, `label`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In your origi8nal design you have a combined primary key so you can only make a reference to the combined primary key or define a new one for label

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS org_roles (
>   `org_id` INT NOT NULL,
>   `label` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`org_id`, `label`))
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
>
> -- The users are unique
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
>   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (`id` ASC));
>
> -- The orgs are unique 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organizations (
>   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` TEXT(64) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (`id` ASC))
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
>
> -- The table that match a user in an org with a specified role (= label in the org_role table)
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_in_org (
>   `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
>   `org_id` INT NOT NULL,
>   `role` TEXT(32) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `org_id`),
>   UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC));
>
>
>
> ALTER TABLE user_in_org ADD
>   (CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__users1
>     FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`id`)
>     ON DELETE CASCADE
>     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
>   CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__organizations1
>     FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES organizations(`id`)
>     ON DELETE CASCADE
>     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
>   CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__org_roles1
>     FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`,`role`) REFERENCES org_roles(`org_id`,`label`)
>     ON DELETE RESTRICT
>     ON UPDATE CASCADE);
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e9237b2a92259ea4e7ecdfe6fe2baa1)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
So I did this way : 
```sql
ALTER TABLE students.user_in_org ADD
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_in_org__org_roles1
    FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`, `role`) REFERENCES students.org_roles(`org_id`, `label`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```
But I get the following error :
ER_FK_INCORRECT_OPTION: Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'user_in_org'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'students/fk_user_in_org__org_roles1'

Comment: maybe a typo, as you see in my changed answer it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the table students.org_roles doesn't have Unique index in the field org_id, it is what error says